# Подвинуть элемент под курсор

Tags: jquery

Надо подвинуть элемент под курсор, пробовал через animate и отслеживание через кординаты курсора. Но получилось слишком громоздко и конфликтно (лупа крашилась).

Comment: [Первый ответ поисковика](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
  mousex = e.pageX;
  mousey = e.pageY;
  $('#element_magnify').css({'top':mousey,'left':mousex,'position':'absolute'});
});
```

Не?

Comment: а от высоты элемента можно брать?

Comment: Можно. Добавьте/отнимите соответствующую величину.